# European residence card

Tags: uk, transit-visas, cruising

My name is Tracy. I'm South African and hold a South African passport. I recently moved to Italy. I will be on a Sapphire Princess cruise ship from 4th of April which starts in Messina until 18 May where it ends in  Southampton. The ships home port is Southampton.

I will disembark the ship in Southampton and return back to Italy. I'm legally married to an Italian, and therefore I hold

1. legalised Marriage Certificate
2. Residence card for family member of a European citizen
3. Italian Teserra senitaria card
4. Italian identity card

To fly from Southampton with the following documents and accompanying my husband, will I need a visa to transit through UK?

Answer (score 3):

If you are with your Italian husband and you have your passport and residence card, [you can remain in the UK for basically as long as you want without a visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card).  So no, you will not need a visa for this trip.

In the event that free movement for EU citizens and their family members in the UK ends before you arrive in the UK, you will likely need a visitor in transit visa or a standard visitor visa.

Comment: * presuming the UK doesn't leave the EU in the meantime

Comment: @JonathanReez it's looking rather like free movement will be extended past the UK's departure from the EU, though it's of course by no means certain, but it does seem very likely that the departure date will be delayed until sometime after May.